# Linq to Sql - Use sum in the where clause

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm trying to select orders that have either over or under 2000 products ordered in them, depending on other values.  I need to select the information from the Orders table, but check this value in the OrdersProducts table, specifically the sum of OrdersProducts.ProductQty.  I also need to do this using predicate builder, because of other requirements.  So far, I have this, but it isn't returning the results correctly.  Its using nested Lambda expressions, which I didn't know I could do but I tried it and it works, but its not returning correct results.

```
Dim getOrders = From d In db.Orders _
                Where d.Status = OrderStatus.Approved _
                Select d

' Then a for loop adding parameters via Predicatebuilder... 


If over2000 = True Then
    ' over 2000
    predicate1 = predicate1.And(Function(d) (d.OrderProducts.Sum(Function(c) c.ProductQty > 2000)))

Else
    ' under 2000
    predicate1 = predicate1.And(Function(d) (d.OrderProducts.Sum(Function(c) c.ProductQty < 2000)))

End If

basePredicate = basePredicate.Or(predicate1)


' End For loop

getOrders = getOrders.Where(basePredicate)
```

I removed some code for brevity but I think that gets the point across.  How can I do this?? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
(d.OrderProducts.Sum(Function(c) c.ProductQty > 2000))
```

to this:

```
(d.OrderProducts.Sum(Function(c) c.ProductQty) > 2000)
```

I haven't built this to test it, but it appears that it was currently trying to sum the results of a boolean comparison instead of summing the quantities and then comparing.

Comment: The sql its building looks a lot better!! And quick response!  I need to get some other things setup to test it and I will let you know if that fixed it or not, can't tell at the moment, but looks better.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey, works like a charm!  Good catch there.  I was actually trying to figure out why I was missing a record that I knew I should be getting... ha, well it was equal to 2000 and I only had less than and greater than, lol.  Thanks again.