# How can i remove columns which contains 0 using lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list which contains suppose 4 columns i want to remove columns which contains 0 from first row to last row. In this case i want to remove 2nd & 4th column how can i achieve this using lambda expression c# 4.0

```
c1  c2  c3  c4
1   0   10  0
2   0   20  0
3   0   30  0
```

o/p should be

```
c1  c2
1   10
2   20
3   30
```

Comment: A list containing columns? Are you using a list of lists, jagged arrays or datatables?

Comment: sorry a list contains properties c1,c2,...

Comment: How do you mean your list contains 4 columns? Does your list contain your own objects, each of which has several 'row' values? Do you have a list of lists (of ints?)

Comment: Could you please be more specific, maybe show some code which shows your data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove properties from an object. You should turn your data into something where columns can actually be removed, like a list of lists:

```
List<List<int>> list = originalList.Select(
  i => new List<int>(){ i.c1, i.c2, i.c3, i.c4 }
).ToList();
```

Now you can examine the data in the list and remove columns:

```
int i=0;
while (i < list[0].Count) {
  if (!list.Any(x => x[i] != 0)) {
    foreach (List<int> item in list) {
      item.RemoveAt(i);
    }
  } else {
    i++;
  }
}
```

An alternative would be to mirror the list diagonally, i.e. turn it into a list of columns that contain data for each item instead of a list of items that contain columns. That would make it a bit easier to remove the columns, but some other actions will be harder, for example sorting the items.

Comment: Performing Any() with (x[i] != 0) would be faster (for lists that are not all zeroes)

Comment: I have really basic experience with "dynamic" keyword in .NET 4, but I think that although he can't remove properties from the object, with dynamic, I am almost certain he could create a new object with only specific properties. I would, however, discourage the usage of dynamic in this context, but hey, it's not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'SUM' in where clause of your LINQ query. It could be something like where sum of column C2 greater than zero. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911508/linq-to-sql-use-sum-in-the-where-clause) may be helpful to you.

Comment: Assuming that there is only positive data in the list.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my another comment, Any() would be faster than All(), but it would be faster than Sum() too. The reason is that both Sum and All go thru all items in a collection, while Any will stop the moment it finds an element that satisfies the condition. And if you negate the condition, like in my answer, you will get a more performative solution. And like Guffa said, Sum() is wrong because it assumes either all positive or all negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have lists implemented as nested lists, you could do something like:

```
List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>();

// fill data here
// ...
// ...

List<List<int>> filtered = lists.Where(lst => lst.Any(num => num != 0)).ToList();
```

If what you need is an object that contains only properties that satisfy a condition, a reflection (or perhaps Dynamic object from .NET 4.0) should be used. And in that case I wouldn't force doing it with lambdas.

Try to explain your data structure in more details so someone can give a useful answer.